# jquery.load() is not working in IE 6

Tags: jquery, iframe

I used a jquery file to upload files ie ajaxuploader without any flash.. 
it loads a iframe on loading the jquery but its not working in IE 6, but it works fine in IE 7
the onload funciton is not working in IE 6,,

i have used a ajaxuploader.js file to do this operation,,, pls help

```
var name = 'iframe_au' + get_uid();
```

// create iframe, so we dont need to refresh page to avoid postback in fileupload

```
this.iframe = $('<iframe name="' + name + '"></iframe>')
.css('display', 'none')
.appendTo('body');
```

---

onload event

```
var iframe = this.iframe;
iframe.load(function(){
  var response = iframe.contents().find('body').text();
});
```

but this onload event is not firing in IE 6 but it works in IE7 etc..

Comment: Are you looking for `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: it a js file and i have given the onload frame code above.. it get into that and inliase the ajax uploding effect.. but itz not geting on the load event in IE6

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult solving the issue with the given information, but you can try wrapping your load function with a `window.setTimeout`.

My guess is that IE6 is trying to load the iframe before it has been successfully added to the browser (and been loaded in the dom).

**EXAMPLE** http://jsfiddle.net/MnUSH/1/

```
$(function() {

    var name = 'iframe_au' + new Date().getTime(); //get_uid()
    this.iframe = $('<iframe name="' + name + '"></iframe>').css('display', 'block').appendTo('body');
    this.iframe.attr('src', '/somepage'); //This will return a 404 page

    var iframe = this.iframe;

    window.setTimeout(function() {

        iframe.load(function() {
            var response = iframe.contents().find('body').text();
            alert(response); //Alerting response
        });

    }, 200);


});
```